# Trying to do a reset test in Rstudio

Tags: r, testing, rstudio, regression, reset

I'm trying to do a reset test in Rstudio. Im new to this.
This is my code:

```
model1 <- lm(inntekt ~ arbeidstid + kvinne + alder + leder + utd_hoy, data = d)
summary(model1)

install.packages("lmtest")
library("lmtest")

resettest(lm, power = 2:3, type = "regressor", data = d)
```

When i am trying to run the test i get this:

> resettest(lm, power = 2:3, type = "regressor", data = d)
>   Error: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Can somebody pleas help me? I am happy for all answers :)

Answer (score 1):

May be because you should write name of lm object, not just `lm` :

```
resettest(model1, #replace lm by model1
power = 2:3, type = "regressor", data = d)
```